# Outer product of a vector with itself M-times

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I would like to create a M-mode, n-dimensional tensor A from a vector x of length n such that

```
A_[i_1, i_2, ... , i_M] = x[i_1] * x[i_2] * ... * x[i_M].
```

The code that I have so far is

```
A=np.multiply.outer(x,x)
for i in range(M-2):
    A=np.multiply.outer(A,x)
```

I'm rather new to coding in Python so I'm not sure if there is a more compact/convenient way of computing this tensor.

Answer (score 4):

We could make use of [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) to create open grid versions of input array and then feed those to [`np.multiply.reduce`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html) for element-wise multiplication reductions for all of those, like so -

```
A = np.multiply.reduce(np.ix_(*[x]*M))
```

---

**Extending to other supporting ufuncs**

We could extend this to other ufuncs that have the `reduce` method. So, for example to perform outer `addition`, it would be -

```
np.add.reduce(np.ix_(*[x]*M))
```

and so on.

For a complete list of `ufuncs` that support this feature, please refer to the [**`docs`**](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/ufuncs.html). After `Grep`-ing for those, I got the following ufuncs that support `reduce` method and hence could leverage the earlier posted approach :

> add, subtract, multiply, divide, logaddexp, logaddexp2, true_divide,
>   floor_divide, negative, positive, power, remainder, mod, fmod, divmod,
>   absolute, fabs, rint, sign, heaviside, conj, exp, exp2, log, log2,
>   log10, expm1, log1p, sqrt, square, cbrt, reciprocal, gcd, lcm, sin,
>   cos, tan, arcsin, arccos, arctan, arctan2, hypot, sinh, cosh, tanh,
>   arcsinh, arccosh, arctanh, deg2rad, rad2deg, bitwise_and, bitwise_or,
>   bitwise_xor, invert, left_shift, right_shift, greater, greater_equal,
>   less, less_equal, not_equal, equal, logical_and, logical_or,
>   logical_xor, logical_not, maximum, minimum, fmax, fmin, isfinite,
>   isinf, isnan, isnat, fabs, signbit, copysign, nextafter, spacing,
>   modf, ldexp, frexp, fmod, floor, ceil, trunc

Comment: Curiously your `ix_` approach is 2x or more times slower the OP's loop.

Comment: Thanks! 

Just so I can understand what's going on, could you elaborate on the `*[x]*M` inside ix()?  Is that a notation within Python, or some property of ix -- it isn't mentioned in the reference guide you linked?

Comment: @Gillithonnen Basically creates copies of x as a list with `[x]*M` and then unpacks with `*[x]*M` so each of the copies are fed as one input each to `np.ix_` that creates open grids out of them.