# Most efficient way to make a max result matrix from other matrices in numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, numpy

I'm doing some image signal processing in python and I'm still new to the numpy functions and how to do it in the best way.

Scenario:
 I have four matrices g1,g2,g3,g4 they all have the same shape W,H.

I need to make a result matrix max_g where every max_g[i, j] = max(gk[i,j])

I was looping the entire image and doing:

```
max_g = np.zeros(Y_channel.shape)
grads = np.array([np.abs(signal.fftconvolve(Y_channel, g_filter, mode='same')/16.0) for g_filter in g_filters])

for i in range(W):
    for j in range(H):
        max_g[i, j] = np.max([grad[i, j] for grad in grads])
```

It's okay for 512x512 images but it is too slow for bigger images like 1280x720, is there a more efficient way of doing it? I mean better then 0(WxH)

Comment: Relevant - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53932846/

Answer (score 2):

You have a list containing your arrays, just `stack` them and take the max along the first axis.

***Setup***

```
np.random.seed(1)
H = 5
W = 5
grads = [np.random.randint(1, 10, (W, H)) for _ in range(4)]
```

---

#### `stack` + `max`

```
np.stack(grads).max(0)
```

```
array([[6, 9, 9, 6, 9],
       [9, 8, 9, 8, 8],
       [8, 8, 9, 4, 8],
       [9, 8, 9, 8, 5],
       [7, 9, 9, 9, 7]])
```

---

***Validation***

```
max_g = np.empty((W, H))
for i in range(W):
    for j in range(H):
        max_g[i, j] = np.max([grad[i, j] for grad in grads])

np.array_equal(max_g, np.stack(grads).max(0))
```

```
True
```

---

***Timings***

```
H = 720
W = 1280
grads = [np.random.randint(1, 10, (W, H)) for _ in range(4)]

%timeit np.stack(grads).max(0)
14.8 ms ± 190 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
max_g = np.empty((W, H))
for i in range(W):
   for j in range(H):
       max_g[i, j] = np.max([grad[i, j] for grad in grads])

10.2 s ± 98.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

As you can see, quite a speedup.

Comment: Or reduce : `np.maximum.reduce(grads)`?

Comment: @Divakar it seems like that's about as fast as stacking w/ max, but definitely more apparent what's being done, I'll add it to the comparisons!

Comment: I guess the perf would show up with large number of arrays in that list.

Comment: Yep, looks like it improves on larger lists, also, I'm sure it's much more memory efficient

Comment: Thanks @user3483203 for the nice explanation it is way better but i'm going with Divakar's solution using reduce.