# Calling func.outer on N arrays with N arguements

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I asked a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59480817/recursive-function-to-apply-any-function-to-n-arrays-of-any-length-to-form-one-j)

How would the accepted answer then be applied to a function with multiple parameters, as the outer function only takes two arrays, rather than N arrays

So given a function:

```
def func(velocity, distance, mass, g):
    return velocity*distance/mass/g
```

How would `.outer` or a similar method be applied here?

Comment: Describe the dimensionality of the inputs?  And expected output? For example is `g` is a scalar (constant)?

Comment: Beware that each operator in you example is many times faster than a `frompyfunc` application.  `frompyfunc` tends to be only 2x faster than an explicit python iteration.  Your quest for generality might produce slow code.

Comment: Have you studied the docs for `np.frompyfunc`?  You won't get far with this approach if you don't understand function well.

Comment: A function like that can be called directly with arrays (and scalars) that broadcast against each other.  `*` and `/` are performed by the `ufunc`, `np.multiply` and `np.divide`.

Comment: @TomMartin I would suggest you to complete your question to be self-consistent. It is OK to relate to a previous question, but I would not do it at the expenses of having a question that, as is, it is difficult to grasp.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same ideas from [my answer to your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59481056/5218354), you could basically use the same technique to craft a view of the inputs in a way that broadcasting will work correctly:

```
import numpy as np


def multi_broadcast(arrs):
    for i, arr in enumerate(arrs):
        yield arr[tuple(
            slice(None) if j == i else None
            for j, arr in enumerate(arrs) for d in arr.shape)]
```

which can be used directly into your broadcast-compatible function:

```
arrs = [np.arange(1, n + 1) for n in range(2, 2 + 4)]
arr = func(*multi_broadcast(arrs))
print(arr.shape)
# (2, 3, 4, 5)
```